# how do I wait for value to change in html using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

Im making a chrome extension that buys automaticly, but sometimes the website is a little slow and it can take some time for the item to load that is has been put in the basket. The "put in basket" button looks like this:

```js
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to basket" class="button">
```

And when it is done loading the button change to this:

```js
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="remove" class="button remove">
```

How do i wait for the button to change and then go to check out page? Right now i have this code:

```js
if ($(".button[name=commit]").val() == "remove"){
     window.open("checkout page");
   }
```

But the checkout page dosen't open because the value is "add to basket" at the time the page load. Hope this wasn't too confusing

Comment: If the answer helped remember to mark it as correct :) Good luck!

Comment: It didn't work sry tried my best :(

Answer (score 1):

I will post a generic example so you can adapt to your problem:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to basket" class="button">

$( document ).ready(function() {
   // Add a listener on your button
   document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].addEventListener('change', doSomething);
});

function doSomething(){
   alert('change');
}
```

When your input value changes from 'add to basket' the doSomething callback will be called.